# I don't understand why this is doing this action? I just need it explained

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I just need something explained to me. When we declare ints It was my notion that it doesn't matter where you declare it as long as its in the beginning so I made this little bit of code to print out a multiplication table.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Learn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int last = 5;
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= last){
           int j = 1;
           while (j <= last) {               
               System.out.print(i*j);
               System.out.print(" " );
               j = j + 1;
           }
           System.out.println();
           i = i + 1;
       }
   }
}
```

This prints out.

1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25

but If I take the int j = 1; and I put it outside of the while loop above it it only prints out 1 2 3 4 5. Why does this happen?

Comment: It's not the declaration that's the problem - it's that you're changing the value to 1. If you put the declaration outside the loop and place `j = 1` where your declaration currently is, you'll get the same result.

Comment: its called variable scope, more information here: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Answer (score 2):

If `j = 1` is inside the loop, then it will be reset every-time that the outer loop loops.

If not it will not be reset and the condition of `j <= last` will not be true on subsequent loops.

Answer (score 0):

When you put j outside the while loop, it's value will be initially 1 and will  continue accumulating/increasing
but if j will be inside the first while loop, j will be initially 1 until 5 only. It is because it is always set to 1 every time 1 loop is executed.

To correct your notion:

> You had also initialize the variable **j** aside from declaring it.

Declaring:

> int j;

Initializing:

> int i;

Initializing and Declaring:

> int j=1;

:)